# d3 form submission, seems to skip preventDefault so it reloads the page when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, forms, d3.js

I am trying to make a form in d3 that doesn't reload the page when "submit" is clicked, but the contents of the function that tells it to do so seem completely skipped every time I submit, so the page reloads(i.e. it doesn't stop if I put a breakpoint inside the function). This happens in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Code for the form:

```
     var attachSectionSelector = function(parentSelector, audioController)
{
    var selection = d3.select(parentSelector)
        .append("form")
        .append("label")
        .text("Selection:  ");


    selection.append("label")
        .text("From: ")
        .append("input")
        .attr({
            "name": "from",
            "id":"from",
            "type":"number",
            "min":"0",
            "step":"1",
        });
    selection.append("label")
        .text("Until: ")
        .append("input")
        .attr({
            "name": "until",
            "id":"until",
            "type":"number",
            "min":"0",
            "step":"1",
        });
    /*for (var i=0; i<100; i+=1)
    {
        selectBegin.append("option").attr("value", String(i)).text(String(i));
        selectEnd.append("option").attr("value", String(i)).text(String(i));
    }*/
    selection.append("input")
        .attr({
            "name": "selection",
            "id":"selection",
            "type": "submit",
            "value": "Select"
        });

    selection.on("submit", function()
        {
            d3.event.preventDefault();
            var fromValue = document.getElementById("from").value;
            var untilValue = document.getElementById("until").value;
            if (fromValue <= audioController.getStopIndex() && untilValue >= audioController.getNotesIndex() && fromValue >= 0){
                audioController.setNotesIndex(fromValue);
                audioController.setStopIndex(untilValue);
            }
        });
};
```

From what I can see the function after "submit" never gets called on submit.

Comment: Could you implement a working example on JSFiddle ?

Comment: It involves midi files and loading json from another url with d3.json, I<m not sure how to implement all of it in a fiddle... parentSelector is ".piano-roll" and holds the graph that will later be affected by this form, but I know that the problem is just in this form.

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems with this form that I can fix later, but what worked was simply changing the name and id of the appended button to something other than "selection" (the last selection.append), it was probably conflicting with the container.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. You need to have unique ID's :)